# Adjusting title margin in Posterdown R package

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am making a poster in RMarkdown using posterdown (https://github.com/brentthorne/posterdown). I want to move the title so that there is more white space between it and the edge of the poster.

Here is the YAML of the template:

```
---
title: Generate Reproducible & Live HTML and PDF Conference Posters Using RMarkdown
author:
  - name: Brent Thorne
    affil: 1
    orcid: '0000-0002-1099-3857'
  - name: Another G. Author
    affil: 2
affiliation:
  - num: 1
    address: Department of Earth Science, Brock University
  - num: 2
    address: Department of Graphics and Layouts, University of Posters; Canada
column_numbers: 3
logoright_name: https&#58;//raw.githubusercontent.com/brentthorne/posterdown/master/images/betterhexlogo.png
logoleft_name: https&#58;//raw.githubusercontent.com/brentthorne/posterdown/master/images/betterhexlogo.png
output: 
  posterdown::posterdown_html:
    self_contained: false

---
```

I tried to make the title a character string with a break, but that causes way too much white space.

```
"<br/>Generate Reproducible & Live HTML and PDF Conference Posters Using RMarkdown"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CSS [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin):

F.e.:

```
title: <div style="margin:20px">Generate Reproducible & Live HTML and PDF Conference Posters Using RMarkdown </div>
```

---

**... to avoid warnings (knit via console):**

*a) quiet:*

```
library(rmarkdown)
render("my_file.Rmd", output_options = list(pandoc_args = c('--metadata', 'pagetitle=Test')))
```

*b) super quiet:*

```
library(rmarkdown)
render("my_file.Rmd", output_options = list(pandoc_args = c('--metadata', 'pagetitle=Test')), quiet = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you. It renders, but I see `[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty title element. Please specify either ‘title’ or ‘pagetitle’ in the metadata.`  I'm not sure how to resolve the warning. Any insight?

Comment: @clc Look to an addition